# How can I find a string separated by a space in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find a way where I can skim out records of customers where 'First Name' and 'Middle Name' has been entered in the first_name column in the customer detail table. For examples

```
first_name, Last_name, mobile_no
Mary Jane     Smith     0400000000
Shane Angus   John      0400000000
Rudy          Gill      0401111111
Rachel        Rose
```

from the above examples I only want to find records

```
Mary Jane     Smith     0400000000
Shane Angus   John      0400000000
```

Comment: Hi @DaleK I have tried patindex(' ',pa2.First_Name) >0 and same with CHARINDEX(' ',pa2.First_Name) >0 but I havn't been able to get the desired result. To be honest I have been scouring though internet to find a workable solution.

Comment: [edit] that and any other clarifications directly into your question.

Comment: Hi @MeysamAsadi I have customer records where customer's middle name has been entered in the fist_name column. This is not right. I am trying to write a code to separate those customer records where first name and middle name has been entered.

Comment: where first_name like '% %'?

Comment: You are over thinking it, just search for space with wild card in between. `WHERE pa2.First_Name like '% %'`.  If you have bad data with leading and trailing spaces, you'll have to trim spaces on both end first.

Comment: Hi @AXMIM thanks for the advice. I am a novice at SQL therefore you could be right. I might be over thinking this. I tried the solution you and Gordon advised below but without the trim function. I will try again with the trim. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `like`:

```
select t.*
from t
where first_name like '% %';
```

Note:  This just checks for a space.  It does not guarantee that one of the names is a middle name.

Comment: Hi @gordon thanks for your response. I tried this solution and it is works. It was a simple solution. I just on the tangent of trying patindex() and charindex() and got lost. :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

here's another solution for you if you want to get more complex and account for the middle name.

```
create table test (first_name nvarchar(50), middle_name nvarchar(50), last_name nvarchar(75), mobile_no nvarchar(10))

insert test
select 'mary jane', null, 'smith', '0400000000'
union all
select 'shane angus', null, 'john', '0400000000'
union all
select 'rudy', 'jacob', 'gill', '0401111111'
union all
select 'rachel', 'liza', 'rose', '0400000000'

select *
from test
where middle_name is null and charindex(char(32),first_name) > 0
```

this won't help you though if the first name is double-worded like Bobby Jo hence the middle name check.